# NullReferenceException on ValueProviderFactoryCollection ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, model-view-controller

My ASP.NET MVC website sometimes is throwing this error:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext) +69
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +76
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1082
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +463
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +45
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +68
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163

Here is my ActionHeader :

```
    public ActionResult Index(string tri = "Date_creation Desc", string parti = "0"){
if (Session["Utilisateur"] != null)
            {
                CroisementsModel lc = new EquilibreRepository().GetAllMessages((int)Session["id_Groupe"], tri, parti);
                lc.utilisateur = Session["Utilisateur"].ToString();
                return View("Index", lc);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", null);
}
```

When this error happens, I need to restart IIS website, and all worked perfect for a certain amount of times.

If someone has an idea...

Edit:
The error come from this function, in global.asax, i used to enable CrossDomainRequest:

protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {

```
    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

}
```

Comment: Complete error:

Comment: Can you show us the code for `Index` method?

Comment: this exception is caused by an object not being instantiated. Open the project and attach a debugger to the IIS process. A web service that is consuming the ASP.NET page is throwing the exception or You could try to troubleshoot this issue with windbg following this link:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/techreflections/2015/05/31/troubleshooting-null-reference-exceptions-in-live-asp-net-applications/